# AWS Serverless Application Model init error on Pycharm

Tags: amazon-web-services, pycharm, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to create a new AWS Serverless Application on Pycharm  but i am getting this error:

```
Could not execute `sam init`!: [Cloning from https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli-app-templates (process may take a moment),
Error: Unstable state when updating repo. Check that you have permissions to create/delete files
```

How can i solve this problem ?

```
Details:

OS:Windows 10 , x64
Version: Python 3.9, SAM CLI- 1.53.0
IDE: Pycharm 2022.1.3 Pro Edition
Git Version 2.37
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay here is the problem why it occurs and the solution for Windows users:

The problem was with the path ("AWS SAM") in Windows that has a space causes the problem:
By calling the --location arg and puting the full path in double quotes it works

> sam init --location "C:\Users[your_user_name]\AppData\Roaming\AWS
> SAM\aws-sam-cli-app-templates\python3.9\cookiecutter-aws-sam-hello-python"

Ref: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/1891

Thanks to:

https://github.com/hawflau

https://github.com/john-zenden

Answer (score 7):

Open PowerShell in admin mode and type this and execute

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" `
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

worked for me. (fixes webstorm aws toolkit error in init too)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am very much new to AWS SAM.You are a saviour,thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

On my windows machine, I fixed it by setting LongPathsEnabled to 1 in the registery:

- Open Registry Editor (regedit.exe).
- Navigate to
  Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
- Set LongPathsEnabled to 1.

This sets Git to allow long paths

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the solutions worked for me. Instead:

1. Open Registry Editor (regedit.exe).
2. Navigate to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
3. Set LongPathsEnabled to 1

Copied from: https://lightrun.com/answers/aws-aws-sam-cli-permissions-error-unstable-state-when-updating-repo

Answer (score 0):

Run this in powershell (as admin)

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" `
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

works for me